# extend btn-group in bootstrap saas hangs browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

I use bootstrap and compass in my project, and after some changes I discovered that when I try to inspect my page with chrome, the browser just hangs. I managed to separate the problematic code from rest of application, and then I realize that the reason of browser crash is to complicated css generated from extending btn-group class.

For example when I have such simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article class="container">
            <header class="page-header">
                <div class="actions">
                    <a class="edit" href="#"><span class="icon"></span></a>
                    <a class="remove" href="#"><span class="icon"></span></a>
                </div>
                <h1 class="title">Some title</h1>
            </header>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

And such scss:

```
@import "compass";
@import "variables";
@import "bootstrap";

@mixin list-component($columns) {
  @include make-md-column($columns);

  li {
    @include clearfix;

    .controls {
      //the problem is here
      @extend .btn-group, .btn-group-sm;
    }
  }
}

.notepads, .last-viewed-notes {
  @include list-component(3);
}

.last-changed-notes {
  @include list-component(6);
}
.notes {
  @include list-component(3);
}

.actions {
  @include clearfix;
  @extend .btn-group, .btn-group-lg;

  a, button {
    //or the problem is here
    @extend .btn, .btn-default;

    .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon;
    }
    &.edit .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon-edit;
    }
    &.remove .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon-trash;
    }
  }
}
```

With that code, generated css have very long and complicated selectors and this selectors kills browser when I try to inspect buttons on my page(I use styles that includes list-component in my html, but I remove them from code of these sample for better view of situation).

Has anyone some idea how to optimize this code?

Like I said in my comment: here is full test project: http://we.tl/bk8KB1cjIQ

About the suggested solution: of course I could simply use bootstrap classes instead of my own, but the I loose nice semantic document and end with a lot of boilplate. Second option could be write own styles for this groups, but I dont want to reinvent the wheel. Finally I could copy-paste scss from bootstrap github to my mixin, but this is a lots of work to do which I be glad to omit.

To be honest, I don't see any other good solution, but maybe someone would come up with some nice idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's **really** difficult to identify where your code is going wrong, because you haven't provided enough of it. What's in `variables`? What's in `bootstrap`? What exists for the mixins and the elements you're extending? But assuming the problem **is** in the blocks you've identified with comments, let's talk a little about how Sass is going to unpack those sections:

```
@mixin list-component($columns) {
  @include make-md-column($columns);

  li {
    @include clearfix;

    .controls {
      //the problem is here
      @extend .btn-group, .btn-group-sm;
    }
  }
}
```

Your `list-component` mixin includes everything from `make-md-column` based on `$columns`, a child `li` declaration which includes everything from `clearfix`, and a child `.controls` declaration which includes **every** declaration for `.btn-group` and `.btn-group-sm`.

```
a, button {
    //or the problem is here
    @extend .btn, .btn-default;

    .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon;
    }
    &.edit .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon-edit;
    }
    &.remove .icon {
      @extend .glyphicon-trash;
    }
  }
```

Your `a` and `button` delcaration (nested inside `.actions`) is going to extend every declaration for `.btn` and `.btn-default`, and create declarations for each of `a .icon, button .icon, a.edit .icon, button.edit .icon, a.remove .icon, button.remove .icon` which will extend **every** declaration for the .glyphicon-* classes.

Yeah, those are gonna compile to **a lot** of CSS.  So, maybe you want to look at those mixins and make them a little more atomic or dynamic, or how many styles are actually coming from the `btn-*` declarations.

Comment: Thank for help and, yes you're right, there will be a lot of css and this is the problem. But it's hard to make this problem solved becouse bootstrap and variables are library files from bootstrap. The bootstrap is well documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/ https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass. But I cannot find the solution in this sources, so I asked for help. Tommorow I can make a sample project with two files that I  attach to my question. Thanks for more detail explanation of the problem.